# How to optimize hybrid app for iphone6/6+

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html, cordova

I am working on a hybrid app which works fine on all the iphones except iphone6/6+
The images,fonts,input boxes in the app appearing large and blur on iphone6/6+ in comparison  to other older version of iphones
Since iphone6/6+((IOS 8)) auto scaling it,so how to stop scaling or downscale those elements(images,input field and fonts),so they appear uniform across all the iphones

Comment: Have you add default images that support iPhone 6/6+ device?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create default images that supports iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ in your Image Assets file.

Alternatively, you can also use a Storyboard/Xib to dynamically create these default images.